# nodejs app crashes after inactivity on database connection

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

i am writing a nodejs webservice that will accept JSON and enter it into a mysql table using (https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql).

my service works fine if no data is passed to it and does not timeout( so basically the app keeps running , but as soon as i send a request with JSON data and then the data is entered into the mysql table. Once that is done the node app gets killed after some idle time, with the following error

```
Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
at Protocol.end (/home/user/sqlconnector/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:103:13)
at Socket. (/home/user/sqlconnector/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:102:28)
at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
at _stream_readable.js:920:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I am looking for a graceful way to just exit the sql connection when done processing but not killing the nodejs app.
I can counter it by using something like forever to restart the app on crash but what i want to understand is their a fundamental mistake in the code...

Here is the snippet of my code for inserting data...

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'xxxx',
  user     : 'xxx',
  password : 'xxxx',
  database : 'test'
});

var app = express();
// set our port
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;        

// parse application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json())

// get an instance of the express Router
var router = express.Router();              

// POST / gets json data 
router.post('/', function(req, res) {       

    var data = req.body[0].record;

    // INSERT INTO posts SET `name` = 'hello', `name2` = 'hello2'
    // inserting data into the parent level form
    var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO '+ tablename +' SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(result.insertId);

    });
    console.log("Parent \n" + query.sql); 
    res.send("Post Received: statusCode:" + res.statusCode);

});

app.use('/api', router);

// START THE SERVER
app.listen(port);
console.log('Magic happens on port ' + port);
```

Answer (score 1):

The docs have a lot about this. [See here.](https://github.com/felixge/node-mysql#terminating-connections)

Pretty much you can just call `connection.end()` after your query finishes. So something like

```
// it implicitly opens the connection by querying
connection.query('INSERT INTO '+ tablename +' SET ?', data, function(err, result) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result.insertId);
    connection.end();
});
```

Comment: On a side note, I'm just wondering why you have the `[0]` in `var data = req.body[0].record;`?

Comment: i have a [0] because that is the way my incoming Json is formatted a little odd than usual

Comment: nope sorry that suggestion does not work i still get connection timed out

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I used pm2 module to restart the server when the connection is timeout you can see other solutions here
[Node JS auto restart all forever JS process when server goes down / crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197099/node-js-auto-restart-all-forever-js-process-when-server-goes-down-crashes)