# What is the best design for a Node application using 'mssql' library that handles many requests per day?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, node-mssql

I'm trying to optimize (and safeguard against crashes/errors) my application which will need to execute hundreds or thousands of SQL queries daily, and I'm wondering what the best design/setup is for mssql.

I know it probably wouldn't be efficient to use `await sql.connect()` and for each query (this seems to be slower as well).

What I've done before is the following:

`sql.js`

```js
const sql = require('mssql');
const config = require('./util/db-config.js');

async function connect () {
    await sql.connect(config)
}

async function someDatabaseFunction () {
    await sql.query('sql statement').then((table) => {
        //do stuff here
    }
}
module.exports = {connect, someDatabaseFunction}
```

`app.js`

```js
const express = require('express');
const {connect, someDatabaseFunction} = require('./sql.js'); 
const app = express();

connect()

app.post('/someroute', async (req, res) => {
    await someDatabaseFunction()
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Running on port 3000!'))
```

So basically I do `const sql = require('mssql')` on a global scope (is that what it's called?) in `sql.js`, and run the `connect()` function on startup of the app, and then any functions inside `sql.js` use the global connection pool to execute queries.

This has worked for me before but as I develop for larger scale and more critical operations, I worry about what might happen if the connection to the database breaks/fails... Is there like a "best practice" for this kind of setup?

Comment: `await sql.connect()` is not necessarily slow, due to connection pooling, you just need to make sure to close and dispose it after you're finished (and create a new one each time). Make sure you always use `await`

Answer (score 0):

You should begin by wrapping your db calls in try/catch statements to be able to catch failed queries and crashes. Then handle them by reseting the connection or rectifying/cancelling the query.

It will still be a lot perfectible, especially if you need to abstract things to scale up, but it should increase a bit the robustness of the application.

Propper error handling is always good practice!

Comment: Ah yes, I forgot to include this in the example code but I do do this, I guess I'm just not sure what the best way of going about resetting the connection is...

Comment: Await for an other db.connect() on db connection errors seems ok.
However I didn't go further on my answer because I'm not experienced enough to give you best practices for your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

you probably can get around this issue by doing the following in your index file

/** all of your routes get configured over here*/

```
connect().then(
 app.listen(3000=>console.log('Running on port 3000!'))
).catch((err)=>{

 console.log("Unable to connect to db", err);
 process.exit(1);
})
```

basically what this does is we try establishing a connection to the db when the server starts , if not then we gracefully shut down the process.

you ideally want something to restart the application and also set up healthchecks for a lb if you have one to direct traffic else where if the application is not healthy.

see here for restarting your application : [Node JS auto restart all forever JS process when server goes down / crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37197099/node-js-auto-restart-all-forever-js-process-when-server-goes-down-crashes)

for nodejs best practices see here: https://github.com/goldbergyoni/nodebestpractices